# VB.NET ~ httpwebrequest -How to obtain form element id's/names during an httpwebrequest

Tags: html, vb.net, forms

What I would like to know is how to obtain form input elements during an httpwebrequest?

```
id=username
id=password
```

Is it possible to obtain these input elements during an httpwebrequest without having to view the html code?

Comment: Do you want to login to remote website?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the elements from a form request using this code:

```
For Each key As String In HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.Keys
   Dim value as string = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form(key)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I am getting an error stating item not declared. For Each key As String In HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.Keys

Comment: This does not work. Do you have another method to use? Thanks

Comment: I think you might need to provide a little more code example or a better explanation about what you are trying to do and in what context.